# Obtaining a function given certain conditions and proving its range (part 1)

Tags: functions

Consider the function $ f:\mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N} $, which is defined by $f(1)=1$ and, for all n≥1,

$$ f(2n) = f(n)$$
$$f(2n+1) = f(n) + f(n+1)$$

Calculate and show the method to obtain the first ten function values, $f(1), f(2),..., f(10)$.

I am completely lost on how to approach such a problem - so far, I've tried doing some guess and check but, unsuprisingly, it turned out to be ineffective. Would concepts such as monotonic, continuous, injective, surjective, or bijective functions help? If so, how? The problem **does not** require one to use these concepts but I am just curious as to how they *could* be of use (if at all)? Any help with this question would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First calculate $f(2), f(4)$ and $f(8)$, in that order. You know what $f(1)$ is, so that should be easy using the first rule, as inserting $n = 1$ gives $f(2) = f(1)$, and so on.

Now calculate $f(3)$, using the second rule, as inserting $n = 1$ gives $f(3) = f(1)+f(2)$, and you already know what $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ are. Then do $f(6)$ using the first rule, inserting an appropriate value for $n$.

Now calculate $f(5)$ using the second rule, inserting an appropriate value for $n$, and then $f(10)$ using the first rule.

Finally, do $f(7)$ and $f(9)$ using the second rule.

Continuity is irrelevant here, as this is a function from the natural numbers to the natural numbers. *All* such functions are continuous, under the standard topology on $\Bbb N$. You could check for properties like injectivity or surjectivity, if you wanted. The first rule more or less immediately rules out injectivity, but surjectivity seems like it would be a more interesting question to pursue.

Comment: Ohhhh okay. So f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 2. f(4) = 1, f(5) = 3. f(6) = 2, f(7) = 3, f(8) = 1, f(9) = 4, and f(10) = 3?

Comment: @AlexanderB Yup. That's all there is to it. I know I said to do it in a certain order (basically apply rule 1 as many times as possible before using rule 2 once, rinse and repeat), but doing it in increasing order like that is just as good.